# JWT - Simple API example

Tags: php, api, authentication, rest, jwt

I have created this fake API just because I want to learn how to use JWT. It is a simple unsigned token exchange with two methods call: login and adminPassword.

I've used https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt as a JWT implementation.

This is the server code (index.php):

```
<?php
// https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Parser;
use Lcobucci\JWT\ValidationData;

define('USERNAME', 'admin');
define('PASSWORD', 'p4ssw0rd');

function login($username, $password) {
  if ($username == USERNAME && $password == PASSWORD) {
    $token = (new Builder())->setIssuer('JWT Example')
      ->setAudience('JWT Example')
      ->setIssuedAt(time())
      ->setExpiration(time() + 3600)
      ->getToken();
    return json_encode(['result' => 1, 'message' => 'Token generated successfully', 'token' => '' . $token,]);
  } else {
    return json_encode(['result' => 0, 'message' => 'Invalid username and/or password']);
  }
}

function validateToken($token) {
  try {
    $token = (new Parser())->parse($token);
  } catch (Exception $exception) {
    return false;
  }

  $validationData = new ValidationData();
  $validationData->setIssuer('JWT Example');
  $validationData->setAudience('JWT Example');

  return $token->validate($validationData);
}

function adminPassword($token) {
  if (validateToken($token)) {
    return json_encode(['result' => 1, 'message' => 'The admin\'s password is: ' . PASSWORD]);
  } else {
    return json_encode(['result' => 0, 'message' => 'Invalid token']);
  }
}

$requestUri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
if ($requestUri == 'users/login') {
  echo login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
} else if ($requestUri == 'users/admin-password') {
  echo adminPassword($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);
}
```

And the following is the client code:

```
<?php
// https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt
define('SERVER_URL', 'http://localhost:9999/');

function httpPost($url, $data = [], $headers = []) {
  $options = [
    'http' => [
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'header'  => array_merge(['Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'], $headers),
      'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ],
  ];
  $context  = stream_context_create($options);
  return file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}

$url = SERVER_URL . 'users/login';
$response = httpPost($url, ['username' => 'admin', 'password' => 'p4ssw0rd']);
$response = json_decode($response);

$url = SERVER_URL . 'users/admin-password';
echo httpPost($url, [], ["Authorization: Bearer <{$response->token}>",]);
```

Dependencies (composer.json):

```
{
    "name": "ns/jwtexampleapp",
    "require": {
        "lcobucci/jwt": "^3.1"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Author name",
            "email": "autho@email.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

The next step is to learn about token signatures.

I know the code could be better. Actually I'm focused on the JWT concepts. Please analyse the code with that in mind ...

Am I following the right path? Is it a good representation about the JWT concepts?